# Why does my .htaccess file only partially force HTTPS and WWW?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, https

I have the domain `https://www.example.com` and this is how I prefer that users reach my site as well, using both HTTPS and WWW.

In my `.htaccess` file I try and force everyone to use this set up with the following code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which seems to work fine, all users that type `example.com` will get directed to the HTTPS version with the www sub domain.

BUT! If a user were to enter `www.example.com` OR `http://www.example.com` they are not redirected to the HTTPS version, what can be causing this?

I'm working on preparing the SEO for that domain as well and SEMRush actually gives me two listings per finding, one for the http version of the site and one for the https version of the site, I'm guessing this has something to do with the redirection issues as well.

**UPDATE**

This is my entire `.htaccess` file as it looks after your last suggested changes:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =goodies.no [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.goodies.no/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^goodies\.no [NC]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.goodies.no/$1 [R=301,L]

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.svg>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
<files *.js>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
<files *.ttf>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
<files *.jpg>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
<files *.png>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I just commented out the part that used to work, and as you can see there are some compression and caching rules there as well.

**UPDATE#2 (ACTUALLY UPDATE 3, NEW TEST.PHP FILE)**

here is the contents of test.php file which is now available at https://goodies.no/test.php

```
<?php

$ip = getenv('SERVER_PORT');
echo "the first variable (SERVER_PORT) is ".$ip;


$ap = getenv('HTTPS');
echo " the second variable (HTTPS) is ".$ap;

$dp = getenv('ENV_HTTPS');
echo " the third (ENV_HTTPS) variable is "$.dp

?>
```

This only outputs the text "the variable is" and nothing else. Am I way off.... I get the feeling that I'm way off .. :/

Comment: "and nothing else. Am I way off...." - that is unusual. (It means Apache is not setting these variables). That certainly explains the redirect loop you were getting. This suggests there is a front end proxy (or load balancer) that is handling the SSL.

Comment: Thanks, I can read any variable that are global (like SERVER_PORT) but the environment variables cannot be read.

Comment: The environment variables are likely to be an empty string (they should still be set). Try assigning the output to a variable and `var_dump($myvar)`. eg. `$envServerPort = getenv('ENV_SERVER_PORT'); var_dump($envServerPort);` - it will be `(bool)false` if not set at all, or `string(0) ""` if just empty.

Comment: Try adding `<pre><?php var_dump($_SERVER); ?></pre>` to your `test.php` file. This will output a lot of information about the system, including (converted) HTTP request headers.

Comment: Just to add, the PHP variables (ie. `SERVER_PORT` and `HTTPS`) are not quite the same as the Apache variables of the same name. If the `ENV_` variables are empty then the Apache variables are not set. If the `SERVER_PORT` and `HTTPS` variables are set then we can do the appropriate redirect in PHP, but that doesn't really help with letting Apache do it.

Comment: Note you have an error in your code - last line. Should be `$dp`, not `dp`.

Comment: Fixed the $dp and added the <pre> line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your logic. Your conditions are implicitly AND'd (the default), they should be OR'd instead. So, currently the `RewriteRule` is only processed if the `HTTP_HOST` is "example.com" AND the `SERVER_PORT` is 80. You need it to trigger on either of these conditions, so you need to add an `OR` flag on the first condition.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(No need for string anchors ie. `^` and `$` if you are capturing the whole pattern.)

**UPDATE:** Alternatively, check the `HTTPS` server variable, instead of `SERVER_PORT`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What that says is... for every request that is not HTTPS *or* is for `example.com` (ie. no `www`) then redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

Alternatively, you can implement this as two separate rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**DEBUGGING:** Test what these server variables contain on your server. You can (temporarily) replace the above redirect with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} (.*)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ENV_SERVER_PORT:%1]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (.*)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ENV_HTTPS:%1]
```

This will create two environment variables (`ENV_SERVER_PORT` and `ENV_HTTPS`) that should be available to your server-side script (eg. PHP). Check what these contain. (eg. in PHP `echo getenv('ENV_SERVER_PORT');`)

Under HTTP you would expect... `ENV_SERVER_PORT` to be `80` and `ENV_HTTPS` to be "`off`".

Under HTTPS you would expect... `ENV_SERVER_PORT` to be `443` (default) and `ENV_HTTPS` to be "`on`".

### Solution

It would seem that the `SERVER_PORT` and `HTTPS` *Apache server variables* are not available. This suggests that you have a front end proxy (or load balancer) that is handling the request.

The related (but *not exactly the same* - despite having the same name) PHP superglobals `SERVER_PORT` and `HTTPS` (specifically `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` and `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`) are, however, being set (by PHP). But `SERVER_PORT` is always 80 when served over HTTP and HTTPS (this also suggests a front-end proxy). The `HTTPS` PHP superglobal is, however, correctly set to "on" when served over HTTPS. But we want to avoid doing this redirection in our code (less efficient, more chance of error).

From your server output, it looks like there is an `X-Proto` HTTP request header (identified by the `HTTP_X_PROTO` index in the `$_SERVER` superglobal array) being set (most probably by the proxy server) when served over HTTPS (it is set to the string "SSL"), but when served over a plain HTTP connection this header is not set. We should be able to check for this in `.htaccess`. Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Proto} !SSL [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For all requests that do not have an `X-Proto` HTTP request header set to the string "SSL" *or* the apex domain is requested then redirect to HTTPS with the `www` subdomain.

Comment: hmm, now my .htaccess looks like this;
`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^goodies\.no [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.goodies.no/$1 [R=301,L]`

But that does not work at all (try it yourself :)

Comment: There's no reason why that should "not work at all" - if your earlier redirect partially worked. Make sure you've cleared the browser cache - earlier 301s will have been cached by any intermediary caches.

Comment: but have you tried opening the site? in chrome it just changes the address line to https://www.    I am using an incognito version of chrome but also tried safari with cleared cache

Comment: it seems as as soon as I enter the OR in the first line the site gets some issues. with only the NC statement there things work, but just not like how I want them to :)

Comment: How is the SSL implemented?

Comment: That is a very good question, my site is hosted at ecowebhosting.co.uk so I'll have to ask them because they are the ones who set up SSL.

Comment: You appear to be getting "too many redirects". This could happen if SSL is only configured as a front-end proxy and not on the site itself. You can examine the server port in your server-side code (eg. in PHP), if it's still port 80 when apparently viewing over HTTPS then that's your problem. You wouldn't have seen this with your original code, but this would affect any HTTP to HTTPS canonical redirect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm creating a support ticket with my hosting provider and crossing my fingers hoping that they will be able to help me sort this out. 
You have been a great help, though.

Comment: Just to add... if that is the case then you might be able to detect HTTPS by  examining the `X-Forwarded-Port` or `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers instead of the `SERVER_PORT` (but your host should be able to answer that).

Comment: Here is the reply from my host: 
Thanks for your reply. The SSL certificate is setup on the server itself for the domain in question using the same IP address. .htaccess rewrite rules will not change from server-to-server, this is a constant across Apache server configurations, but I'm afraid I cannot hep with de-bugging your re-write commands as mentioned, this is beyond the remit of the support we provide.

Comment: Ok, I've added an alternative example to my answer, using `HTTPS` instead of `SERVER_PORT`. Are you able to confirm the server port that your server is seeing when accessed over HTTPS?

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, the redirect errors returned but check my original post for an updated view of my htaccess file where I include all the caching & compression rules as well (not sure if they can interfere in any way)

Comment: WTF? I somehow edited your post, my bad...

Comment: I don't think the caching/compression should influence this at all. Something funny is going on here. You'll need to examine what these server variables contain on your server. I'll add a bit of "debugging" code to my answer.

Comment: This is soooo frustrating :P I truly appreciate the help, though, if we get this sorted I'll happily pay for your assistance ;) But both the rules you supplied as alternatives results in the "too many redirects" error. but as soon as I change back to my original one, the site comes back up, but lets users bypass https though

Comment: so, i'll just write a PHP file to obtain those values and open it in a browser to see? I'll mess around with it for a while and see what I can manage :) when this is all over, I'm buying you a beer!

Comment: Added another update :) I can get results from the variable SERVER_PORT using this setup (which is 8080) but I cannot obtain anything from the custom variables set up in the htaccess file

Comment: And from your results it reports 8080 for both HTTP and HTTPS - which I don't believe is possible if your server is serving the HTTPS request. It strongly suggests you have a front end proxy (or load balancer) that is handling the SSL connection. Also... when the HTTP request leaves the browser it defaults to port 80, so there must be something on route that is changing it to 8080 before hitting your server.

Comment: the 8080 response was my fault, I first set a variable to be equal to SERVER_PORT and then I echoed SERVER_PORT in another line so the response was 80 but I called it twice due to a poorly formatted script.

Comment: Ah OK, so it is port 80, but the same for HTTP and HTTPS? Your test page seems to be outputting an additional "onap ison" on HTTPS?

Comment: I cant get any output from the ENV_HTTPS or HTTPS variables, it is just that my initial script had some crazy formatting.. I'll update my original question now with the format of the current script and please review the output once more at www.goodies.no/test.php because it looks a bit better now :)

Comment: After seeing your server output I've added a possible solution to try.

Comment: Oh man I think we are close! So the site works now, and it opens the HTTPS version when just entering www.goodies.no as well. So the last thing is that it still allows the HTTP version when entering http://www.godies.no .. but just when leaving out the www it opens the HTTPS version, though :)

Comment: hey nevermind! it works just as intended now!! how do I go about sending you money enough for a beer or two? got paypal or something? drop me a line at lund@goodies.no and we'll figure something out